# mojo::useragent and Get Request Parameters

Tags: perl, mojo-useragent

Let's Say I have this  Mojo::UserAgent get request :

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua  = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
print $ua->get('https://google.com?q=mojolicious&format=json');
```

on the above example the get parameters provided as part of the url itself , I am asking if there are an option to separate the request parameters from the url

I tried form but its not achieving the same result like using this directly as url 'https://google.com?q=mojolicious&format=json'

```
print $ua->get('https://google.com' => form => {q= > 'mojolicious' ,format='json'});
```

any idea how to achieve the above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some formatting issues:

- `q= > 'mojolicious` should read `q => 'mojolicious'`
- `format='json'` should read `format => 'json'`
- and you are missing a closing curly `}`

So all in all your line should look like this:

```
$ua->get('https://google.com' => form => {q => 'mojolicious', format => 'json' });
```

This method returns an instance `Mojo::Transaction::HTTP` which you can use like this:

```perl
my $tx = $ua->get('https://google.com' => form => { q => 'mojolicious', format => 'json' });

print $tx->res->body;
```

For further reading please consult https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Transaction::HTTP

Comment: Maybe more usefully read https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent::Transactor#tx — which is where it's documented that yes, `form` *does* work and generate query params for `GET`/`HEAD` requests, along with many handy examples.